# Remove index.php - interior pages are blank

Tags: htaccess, 404, index.php

I've got a site that works correctly on localhost and the staging domain, but after moving to the live server all interior pages return a 404 page.

.htaccess has the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/cms/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

EE is not running in a subdirectory, i've tried adding the query string option from the [docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html) but no change. Also removed the leading slash from index.php but that didn't make a difference.

Any thoughts? hosted on rackspace

Comment: it appears that .htaccess is being deleted by the server. I can see it when uploaded, but when I exit ftp and go back in it's missing. Talking to host now

Comment: this may also be the display settings on your chosen FTP agent, FileZilla by any chance?? http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-can-i-see-my-htaccess-file

Comment: Turns out Rackspace had misconfigured the vhost

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure mod_rewrite is installed & enabled? My guess is no!

Comment: I would also concure with this :) I'd give it 99% chance! Remove your .htaccess (upload a blank one if you're having issues seeing .htaccess) and set your index page to `index.php` to test.

Comment: Agreed. A good way to prove it is to simply remove the "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>" and "</IfModule>" logic. If you get an Internal Server Error afterwards, the module isn't installed.